# How to create 2D array in JMeter

Tags: multidimensional-array, jmeter

I am trying to extract two random values from a single request. I am able to do that using JSON extractor, but I am facing a issue which is to store those values in array. How to store data in 2D array in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help without seeing:

1. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you want to put into the array (names and values, can be seen using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/))
2. The desired format of the array

Most probably you will need to go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) (this guy can [extract data from JSON as well](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) by the way)

Going forward consider being more specific as your question is quite vague